# Why redux multiple initializing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-debugger

[Must be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYR0F.png)

[But this type going to new redux instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzy3i.png)

No problem if I call the action with timeout.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>this.props.isLoggedIn(), 100)
  }
```

Or if I call under render, no problem again.

```
  render() {
    this.props.isLoggedIn()
    ...
    ...
```

This problem occurs only when i call the action under componentDidUpdate on app load. Like that:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.isLoggedIn() //problem
  }
```

Causing the split redux instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem. Interesting with my wrong usage createStore function.

I was calling in render()

```
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)))
    ...
    ...
```

Now i move to out of the top, problem solved.

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        ...
        ...
```